# Formula field to define FCR met or Not Met

Tags: formula, image-formula

trying to build a formula field to define FCR and my formula always turns wrong. The first part works correctly however I'm receiving an

> error : Field Reason_for_Reopen__c is a picklist field. Picklist fields are only supported in certain functions.

```
IF(
    AND(
        IsClosed = TRUE ,
        First_Response_Time__c != NULL
    ), 
    'FCR Met',
    IF(
        AND(
            ISPICKVAL(Reason_for_Reopen__c != 'AUTO REPLY EML'),
            First_Response_Time__c != NULL
        ),
        'FCR Met',
        'FCR Not Met'
    )
)
```

Is there any changes I need to make on my formula or is the use of ISPICKVAL is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You're not using `ISPICKVAL()` correctly.

Taking a look at [the documentation for `ISPICKVAL()`](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions_ispickval.htm&type=5), you'll see that it takes 2 parameters: the picklist field, and the value you want to check.

Note that you can only check if a picklist is currently a certain value. There is no `ISNOTPICKVAL()` function. To do what you want to do, you need to first use `ISPICKVAL()` to say that `Reason_for_Reopen__c` *is AUTO REPLY EML*. Then you can wrap that in a `NOT()` to get the "reopen reason is not auto reply email" that you want.

```java
IF(
    AND(
        IsClosed = TRUE ,
        First_Response_Time__c != NULL
    ), 
    'FCR Met',
    IF(
        AND(
            /* You need to get rid of the "!=" and use a comma so that */
            /*   you're passing the correct number (and type) of parameters */
            /* Then, wrap it in a NOT() so that you end up with the behavior of != */
            NOT(ISPICKVAL(Reason_for_Reopen__c, 'AUTO REPLY EML')),
            First_Response_Time__c != NULL
        ),
        'FCR Met',
        'FCR Not Met'
    )
)
```

Alternatively, `TEXT(Reason_for_Reopen__c) != 'AUTO REPLY EML` would also work

You can also merge the conditions for the first and second `IF()` to remove the second one<sup>1</sup>.

```
IF(
    /* Knowing when to use AND() and when to use OR() takes a bit of experience */
    /* Using AND() is appropriate here */
    AND(
        /* This is common to both checks, so we can factor this out */
        First_Response_Time__c != NULL,
        OR(
            IsClosed = TRUE,
            NOT(ISPICKVAL(Reason_for_Reopen__c, 'AUTO REPLY EML')),
        )
    ),
    'FCR Met',
    'FCR Not Met'
)
```

<sup>1: What you have is effectively `(X && Y) || (X && Z)`. Using the property of distributivity of AND and OR, you can pull out the common part, the `X`. So the expression becomes `X && (Y || Z)`, which using `AND()` and `OR()` functions becomes `AND(X, OR(Y, Z))`</sup>